# CoreData - Unrecognized selector when retrieving entities by their ObjectID

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm developing an application that uses multiple threads to do some intensive calculations as well as fetch a good size of data. Thus, I'm trying to be a good little developer and adhere to [Apple's concurrency guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1) when designing my application with `CoreData`. Basically, I have an `NSOperation` that runs and fetches the data. It returns (to a method in the main thread) an `NSMutableSet` that contains an `NSManagedObjectID` for each of the entities returned.

Here is the method in the main thread where I want to convert those `NSManagedObjectID`s to actual `NSManagedObject` subclasses again:

```
-(void)updateLocalContextWithObjectIDs:(NSMutableSet *)idSet {

    NSMutableSet *entitySet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

    for (NSManagedObjectID *objectID in idSet) {

        [entitySet addObject: (Person *)[[self.dataProvider sharedManagedObjectContext] objectWithID:objectID]];

    }

    self.entitySet = entitySet;
    [entitySet release];

}
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting the following error when this loop runs:

```
-[Person persistentStore]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x619b270
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Calling `persistentStore` on the `Person` object isn't being done by me---it must be happening within `CoreData` and I'm not doing something correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that I was passing in a set of `NSManagedObject`s instead of the set of `NSManagedObjectID`s like I should've been.

This is solved.

Answer (score 1):

### How to solve the "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xXXXX bug"

1. Look for where you called `persistantStore` in your code. Then find where you over-released that object.
2. If you can't find where you are over releasing the object, run [Instruments with NSZombies ON](http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/)

**Explanition**:
Even though your code is not calling `persistantStore` on a `Person`, your computer is. Objective-C is a dynamic language, you're computer has a pointer to a `Person` object and it's sending `persistantStore` to that object. This usually happens when you over released something that you shouldn't have. The object has gone away and a new object has replaced it, however the pointer remains, so when you send a message to that pointer, it goes to the object that now occupies that place in memory.

Comment: "Even though you are not calling persistantStore on a Person, your computer is." - That's exactly what I said. I wasn't saying that Apple's code was bad. I knew it was mine, just not where exactly.

Comment: Sorry I slighly miss-read your question. Fixing now, answer is also for anyone else who may read this later.